# Woocommerce ajax message issue

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I've got this working well except for one small problem.

I have a custom archive-product.php page which shows each product with a quantity selector...

```
<ul class="woo-products">
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 100, 'product_cat' => 'hair-extensions' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>
<li class="product">   
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID); ?>">
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" width="300px" height="300px" />'; ?>
        <?php echo the_excerpt(); ?>
        <span class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></span>                    
    </a>
    <?php // woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product ); ?>
    <?php 
        add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart');
        remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );
    ?>
</li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>
```

If I add a product from there, it goes into my cart no problem. But if I then click on the product to visit it's own page, I see a "this product was added to your cart" message.

Likewise if while on the shop page I add several different products they go into my cart, but if I visit one of those product pages I will see "this product was added to your cart" message several times (once for each product I added to my cart).

Here's an image which might help with my description of the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQC3h.png

In my code above if I un-comment out this line...

```
woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product );
```

...and remove these lines...

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart');
remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );
```

...it works fine except that I don't have the quantity selector option any more.

Any suggestions as to how to stop the "this product was added to your cart" message appearing when I visit a product page after adding it to the cart would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me get around the problem, but including the quantity selectors using a different method the problem went away:

http://christianvarga.com/how-to-add-quantity-to-product-archives-in-woocommerce-and-keep-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in WooCommerce called `wc_clear_notices` That does exactly what you need.

It was introduced in WooCommerce 2.1, you can see the very brief documentation here: http://hookr.io/functions/wc_clear_notices/

See [Woocommerce cart notice showing multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894118/woocommerce-cart-notice-showing-multiple-times) for a way to implement it.