# Woocommerce cart notice showing multiple times

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a function that's working properly except for it displays the notice twice in the cart instead of once. The function applies a discount and also shows a notice.  The function looks for items of a particular category adds the total and if it meets the discount amount it applies the discount and shows a notice. Right now, even if there's only one item in the cart, it's showing the notice twice.

I've tried adding `wc_clear_notices()` but that will clear other notices I need like min max notices for minimum order amounts on categories. If I add in `wc_clear_notices()` at the beginning of the function or in any of the foreach statements it will clear the other min/max notice before it even shows.

Here are some questions I've already looked at but just say to use `wc_clear_notices()` which isn't working because other notices get cleared:

[WooCommerce Notice, run only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40405988/woocommerce-notice-run-only-once)

[Show wc_add_notice only one time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43979665/show-wc-add-notice-only-one-time)

Here's the code I currently have that correctly discounts items and displays notices but displays the notices twice instead of once:

```
//apply discounts to foil and seal product categories
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'cart_count_foil_seal_items',10,1);

function cart_count_foil_seal_items( $cart_object ) {
$seal_prod_tally = 0;
$foil_prod_tally = 0;
// Iterating through each item in cart
foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $item_values ) {
    //  Get cart item data
    $item_id = $item_values['data']->get_id(); // Product ID
    $item_qty = $item_values['quantity']; // Item quantity

    // Getting the object
    $product = new WC_Product( $item_id );
    $prod_cat = wp_get_post_terms($product->get_id(),'product_cat',array('fields'=>'slugs'));

    //tally total
    if (in_array('seal-stickers', $prod_cat)){
        $seal_prod_tally += $item_qty;
    }else if(in_array('foil-badges', $prod_cat)){
        $foil_prod_tally += $item_qty;
    }
}

 foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $item_values ) {

    //Get cart item data
    $item_id = $item_values['data']->get_id(); // Product ID
    $item_qty = $item_values['quantity']; // Item quantity

    // Getting the object
    $product = new WC_Product( $item_id );
    $prod_cat2 = wp_get_post_terms($product->get_id(),'product_cat',array('fields'=>'slugs'));        

    //apply discount to each item within category

      if (in_array('seal-stickers',$prod_cat2)){

        switch ($seal_prod_tally){
            case 20000:
                $item_values['data']->set_price(1327.01/20000);
                if(!is_checkout()){
                    wc_add_notice( 
                            sprintf( 'Quantity discount has been applied to item %s: 20,000 at $1327.01.', $item_values['data']->get_title()
                            ), 'notice' 
                    );
                }
                break;
            case 30000:
                $item_values['data']->set_price(1578.65/30000);
                if(!is_checkout()){
                    wc_add_notice( 
                            sprintf( 'Quantity discount has been applied to item %s: 30,000 at $1578.65.', $item_values['data']->get_title()
                            ), 'notice' 
                    );
                }
                break;
            case 40000:
                $item_values['data']->set_price(1853.05/40000);
                if(!is_checkout()){
                    wc_add_notice( 
                            sprintf( 'Quantity discount has been applied to item %s: 40,000 at $1853.05.', $item_values['data']->get_title()
                            ), 'notice' 
                    );
                }
                break;
            case 50000:
                $item_values['data']->set_price(2126.76/50000);
                if(!is_checkout()){
                    wc_add_notice( 
                            sprintf( 'Quantity discount has been applied to item %s: 50,000 at $2126.76.', $item_values['data']->get_title()
                            ), 'notice' 
                    );
                }
                break;
            case 60000:
                $item_values['data']->set_price(2405.98/60000);
                if(!is_checkout()){
                    wc_add_notice( 
                            sprintf( 'Quantity discount has been applied to item %s: 60,000 at $2405.98.', $item_values['data']->get_title()
                            ), 'notice' 
                    );
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }        
    }else if (in_array( 'foil-badges',$prod_cat2)){
        switch ($foil_prod_tally){
            case 25000:
                $item_values['data']->set_price(5872.63/25000);
                if(!is_checkout()){
                    wc_add_notice( 
                            sprintf( 'Quantity discount has been applied to item %s: 25,000 at $5872.63.', $item_values['data']->get_title()
                            ), 'notice' 
                    );
                }
                break;
            case 50000:
                $item_values['data']->set_price(10815.47/50000);
                if(!is_checkout()){
                    wc_add_notice( 
                            sprintf( 'Quantity discount has been applied to item %s: 50,000 at $10815.47.', $item_values['data']->get_title()
                            ), 'notice' 
                    );
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }            
    }      
 }

}
```

[image: Screenshot of Duplicated Notice in Cart]

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. It looks like the notice it displays for the add fee is actually below the shipping charge in the cart which isn't going to work especially if I have multiple notices. :/ [Screenshot of calculate fees notice](https://i.gyazo.com/8300cc90915c83ca3ae73723b63e3b3c.png)

Comment: It looks like I'll need to check if discounts have been applied after this function runs then display notices? Do you have any ideas on that? Maybe a session variable tied into the cart?

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. I'm not using your code example. The add_fee() adds the discount below shipping which isn't going to work. I was asking if you have alternatives besides the add_fee() example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The multiple notices were caused when the customer updated the cart with the Update Cart button so a quick fix was simply clearing notices every time the customer clicked the Update Cart button.

It would be better to solve the problem at its source which would be finding a different way to display notices without duplication but until then this gets the desired effect.

```
//clear notices on cart update
function clear_notices_on_cart_update() { 
    wc_clear_notices();
}; 

// add the filter 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_update_cart_action_cart_updated', 'clear_notices_on_cart_update', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use wc_has_notice to see if the message has not already been added.

Comment: Consider add some reasoning behind your answer

Comment: ` if (!wc_has_notice('You can apply coupon only for 3 products.', 'error')) { wc_add_notice(__('You can apply coupon only for 3 products.', 'woocommerce'), 'error'); } `   you need to copy paste the message to work it properly. so using conditional operator we can solve this problem. if any one have another great solution I'll be glad to know.